# NullPointerException when trying to read from a text file

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to read these names from a text file, but getting an error. Here's the relevant part of my main method, and the method in question:

```
public class Prog4
{
int mostVoteCount = 0;
int mostVotes = 0;
int mostVotesIndex = 0;
int fewestVoteCount = 0;
int fewestVotes = 0;
int fewestVotesIndex = 0;



String[] candidateArray;
int[] votesArray;

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
  //Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner stdin = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
  int num_votes, num_candidates, election_num = 1;

  System.out.println("Welcome to Prog4!\n");
  Prog4 p4 = new Prog4();

  while (stdin.hasNextLine())
  {
     System.out.println("Results for election " + election_num);
     p4.read_candidates(stdin, p4.candidateArray);
     p4.read_votes(stdin, p4.votesArray);
     System.out.println("Total votes: " + p4.votesArray.length);



  }

 System.out.println("Done. Normal termination of Prog4.");
}
```

and the method in question:

```
public void read_candidates(Scanner stdin, String candidates[])
{
   int candidateCount = 0;
   candidateCount = (stdin.nextInt());

   for (int i = 0; i < candidateCount; i++)
      candidates[i] = (stdin.next());
}
```

Here's my test data used in the "test" text file:

4

Owen

Jack

Scott

Robbie

15 0 1 1 2 3 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 1

Is this the stack trace?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

at Prog4.read_candidates(Prog4.java:75)

at Prog4.main(Prog4.java:35)
```

Comment: Please post the exception with call trace.

Comment: Post your StackTrace.

Comment: Please indicate which is line 75.

Comment: 75 is candidateCount = (candidates.length); and 35 is p4.read_candidates(stdin, p4.candidateArray);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never instantiating your `candidateArray` and `votesArray`, so they are null when you pass them to the `read_candidates` method. I'm guessing it is failing on the line:

```
candidates[i] = (stdin.next());
```

You're basically attempting to do something with a null object (the `candidates` object in this case). At some point in your code you'll have to do something like `candidateArray= new String[]`, and same thing for the `votesArray`, before you attempt to use them.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. It seems impossible though, since I can't know how many array spots to initialize it with until that method runs...

Comment: @CoinBird Consider using an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of a primitive array. The advantage it has is that it will resize itself when it reaches capacity. Note that java Collections can't use primitive types like `int`, so your votes array would have to be `List<Integer>`. The string array is fine as, of course, String is a plain 'ol class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your array "candidates" before you do the assignment

```
public void read_candidates(Scanner stdin, String candidates[]) {

        int candidateCount = 0;
        candidateCount = (stdin.nextInt()); 
        candidates = new String[candidateCount]; // here initialize your array
        for (int i = 0; i < candidateCount && stdin.hasNext(); i++){
            String data = stdin.next();
            System.out.print(data  + " ");
            candidates[i] = data;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be an outfobound exaception so please be careful with the line candidateCount = (stdin.nextInt());

you may get exception here so calculate length correctly candidateCount = candidates.length;

Answer (score 0):

Check the location of test.txt. Based the trace, your Scanner object being passed to read_candidates is null. Be sure that you can read the file from the specified location.